# Inline index definition fails when name is the same as table name

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, create-table, sql-server-2017

SQL Server objects i.e. tables and indexes have their own namespaces. So it is possible to have the same name for index and table(but it's not a common/good practice):

```
CREATE TABLE t(id INT PRIMARY KEY, col INT);
CREATE INDEX t ON t(col);

SELECT * FROM sys.tables WHERE name = 't';
SELECT * FROM sys.indexes WHERE name = 't';
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e718763811cff51aa217372a9748f7f6)**

Unfortunately I am not able to create the same construct using [inline index definition](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/arvindsh/2015/05/31/inline-index-definition-in-sql-server-2016-ctp2/):

```
CREATE TABLE t(id INT PRIMARY KEY, col INT, INDEX t(col));
```

> Msg 2714 Level 16 State 5 Line 1
>
> **There is already an object named 't' in the database.**

```
-- below code is working correctly
CREATE TABLE t(id INT PRIMARY KEY, col INT, INDEX t1(col));
```

**[db<>fiddle demo 2](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=2496dfbb05576ab0946f954193b72d16)**

Do I miss something obvious or is it a bug?

Comment: . . This would appear to be a bug.  Of course, I tend to name indexes as "idx_<tablename>_<columns>".  That makes it much easier to understand messages with the index name.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Yes, I agree that proper naming convention is crucial. I am just curious why seperate statements are ok while inline version ends with error. I also think it is a bug, but first I want to exclude most obvious reasons :)

Comment: What version is your database? As much as I agree this isn't a good naming convention it worked without any issue on my 2014 instance. I don't have anything newer readily available.

Comment: @SeanLange [demo SQL Server 2014](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=003635e54add02444e3e0ddbcb78cf0f) Now I am pretty sure it is a bug :)

Comment: Well that is odd. Worked in 2014 but fails in 2017....seems like a bug to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Do I miss something obvious or is it a bug?

Looks like a bug.

```
CREATE TABLE t(id INT PRIMARY KEY, col INT, INDEX t(col));
```

outputs

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-GDR) (KB4293803) - 14.0.2002.14 (X64) 
    Jul 21 2018 07:47:45 
    Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation
    Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Enterprise 10.0 <X64> (Build 17763: ) (Hypervisor)


(1 row affected)

Msg 2714, Level 16, State 5, Line 4
There is already an object named 't' in the database.
Msg 1750, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.
```

Please add a feedback item here: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server  Especially noting that this is a regression in SQL 2016.

Comment: It was my intention from the beginning but first I always ask for opinion. I will create a case and link to this question. Thanks :)

Comment: For future reference: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/36486877-inline-index-definition-fails-when-index-name-is-t